# redirecting to URL while changing parent path in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, window.location

I have an url:

```
 http://domain/request.php?id=123
```

Now on this site I have a button with a submit handler that is supposed to redirect to

```
 http://domain/submit_solution#/?id=123
```

I tried this:

```
        $('#r_submit_form').click(function()
        {
               window.location = 'submit_solution#/?id=' + $(this).attr('name');
        });
```

But instead of redirecting to

```
  http://domain/submit_solution#/?id=123
```

it just appends

```
 http://domain/request.php?id=123?123=Submit+solution
```

I have tried all kinds of variants with window.location.href.replace but I cant find a way to change the whole url and not just append another part to it. How can it be done?

The rewrite rule for request.php is

```
RewriteRule ^(request|profile|profile_picture|solution|payment)/([0-9]+)$     /$1.php?id=$2 [L] –
```

Answer (score 0):

It appends because you should use the whole domain in your window.location:

```
    $('#r_submit_form').click(function()
    {
           window.location.href = 'http://domain/submit_solution#/?id=' + $(this).attr('name');
    });
```

Comment: You tried to do this with the href? Else if it still redirects you, maybe you should take a look at your request.php, maybe this is redirecting you!

Answer (score 0):

[**window.location**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) has the information you need:

```
    $('#r_submit_form').click(function()
    {
           window.location = window.location.origin + '/submit_solution#/?id=' + $(this).attr('name');
    });
```

Comment: That one redirects me to domain/request.php?123=Submit+solution as well. Could it be related to my request.php rewrite rule? It changes domain/request.php?123 to domain/request/123

Comment: Yes most definitely. Care to post you htaccess rewrite rule?

Comment: RewriteRule ^(request|profile|profile_picture|solution|payment)/([0-9]+)$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L]